# Permission denied when attempting to backup wallet using backupwallet

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-cli, backup

When I call `bitcoin@raspberrypi:~ $ bitcoin-cli backupwallet "backup.dat"`, I get the following error:

error code: -4

error message:

Error: Wallet backup failed!

~/.bitcoin/debug.log shows the following:

> error copying wallet.dat to backup.dat - boost::filesystem::copy_file: Permission denied: "/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat", "backup.dat"

Is it something I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to give permissions to user "bitcoin"?

The wallet is not encrypted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to check ownership and permissions for the files and folders involved. Your current user needs permissions to *read* `/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat` and permissions to *write* to the current directory for `backup.dat`

Try `ls -ld /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat .` and `pwd` and `id`. The permissions will be shown as three triplets for owner, group and others shown as `rwxr-x--- 1 bitcoin pi` which means the owner (user "bitcoin") has read, write and execute permissions (`rwx`), members of the group ("pi") have only read and execute permission (`r-x`) and other people have no permissions at all (`---`). The `id` command will tell you which groups your current use is a member of. The `pwd` will tell you the full name of the current directory where you are trying to write your `backup.dat`

---

To further diagnose the problem try

see if the target already exists and can't be overwritten

```
ls -l backup.dat
mv backup.dat backup.dat.old
echo test > backup.dat
```

see if the source file is readable - look for messages `no read permission`

```
file /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat
```

try to copy it directly

```
cp /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat backup.dat
```

Comment: Thanks,  


`ls -ld /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/new_wallet/wallet.dat` returns "-rw------- 1 bitcoin bitcoin 1462272". 

So the owner (user bitcoin) has read & write permissions, but the group (bitcoin) has no permissions?  

`pwd` returns /home/bitcoin, and `ls -ld /home/bitcoin` returns "drwxr-xr-x 6 bitcoin bitcoin". 


So for the destination folder, user bitcoin has all permissions, but group has r & x only.  

`Id` returns "uid=1001(bitcoin) gid=1001(bitcoin) groups=1001(bitcoin),27(sudo)"

Comment: @Vanderlow: see additional suggestions at end of answer.

Comment: No filename / overwrite conflicts.

I am able to copy the file using `cp`, so I've tested a backup that way and it works fine.  It's strange that I can read and write using `cp` but am unable to do `backupwallet` from within bitcoind.  Could it be something about bitcoind's permissions??

To backup using `cp` I have to stop the bitcoind server running otherwise the wallet file doesn't get backed up properly.  

That's why I wanted to be able to do it using `backupwallet` so I could do it while bitcoind is still running.  Nevermind.

Thanks for your help @RedGrittyBrick